# How to update specific cell value in list where cells are multivalue?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp-powershell

I want to search for a cell value in a list and only update the match where items are multivalue cells. I'm not sure if my terminology is accurate but I hope I can explain what I mean.

I'm able to search and get a match but updating the values for multivalue cells overwrites all the cell values.

I have a minimal test list with one column: User

This column is of the type 'Person or Group'.
In PS the property is called: TypedObject and its value is Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUser

As this type accepts multiple values (email addresses in my case) I added two users here:

```
Add-PnPListItem -List $newList -Values @{"User" = "test1@contoso.com","test2@contoso.com"} -ContentTyp Item
```

If I then try to search for test1@contoso.com and only replace it with test3@contoso.com all the values are replaced, i.e. test2@contoso.com as well:

```
Get-PnPListItem -List "Test" | Where-Object {$_.FieldValues.User.Email -eq "test1@contoso.com} | Set-PnPListItem -List "Test"  -Values @{"User" = "test3@contoso.com"}
```

The result is that the cell doesn't contain two values (test1@contoso.com, test2@contoso.com) but only test3@contoso.com.

Is there a way to only replace one value instead of all of them?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Set-PnPListItem** command is used to update a list item, if you want the updated column contains multiple values, you need to set multiple values in the **Set-PnPListItem** command.

Comment: Thanks. So I actually wanted more like a replace option for one value within a cell that contains multiple values instead of updating the whole cell. I guess that`s not possible as I have not found any other option than to update the whole cell.

Comment: yes, there is no way to replace one value of multiple user column, you need to update the entire column's values.